# Python3.x, Pandas: creating a list of y values depending on the x values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a two data sets that are composed of different x values. It looks like the following.

```
import pandas as pd
data1=pd.csv_read('Data1.csv')
data2=pd.csv_read('Data2.csv')
print(data1)



data1_x data1_y1    data1_y2    data1_y3
-347.2498   0   2   8
-237.528509 0   3   7
-127.807218 0   0   6
-18.085927  11  5   0



print(data2)

data2_x data2_y1    data2_y2    data2_y3
-394.798507 2   0   0
-285.265994 1   0   0
-175.733482 0   0   1
-66.200969  4   0   0
```

I am creating new x that includes all the values by using the following code. `new_x=reduce(np.union1d, (data1.iloc[:,0], data1.iloc[:,0]))`

```
print(new_x)
array([-394.799,-347.25,-285.266,-237.529,-175.733,-127.807,-66.201,-18.0859])
```

Currently, I am trying to create a new y lists for each data set that keeps the same y values if the corresponding x values are present but fills with blank if there is no corresponding x value initially. 
For instance, `print(New_data2)` would look something like this.

```
New_x_data2   New_y1_data2   New_y2_data2   New_y3_data2
-394.799 2   0   0 
-347.25       
-285.266 1   0   0
-237.529      
-175.733 0   0   1
-127.807 0   0   6
-66.201 4   0   0
-18.0859 11   5   0
```

Especially, I am lost in figuring out how to get the new y value. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
from re import sub
repl = lambda x : sub("data\d_(\w+)", "New_\\1_data2", x)
data1.rename(repl, axis = 'columns').append(data2.rename(repl, axis='columns')).sort_values('New_x_data2')
Out[1024]: 
   New_x_data2  New_y1_data2  New_y2_data2  New_y3_data2
0  -394.798507             2             0             0
0  -347.249800             0             2             8
1  -285.265994             1             0             0
1  -237.528509             0             3             7
2  -175.733482             0             0             1
2  -127.807218             0             0             6
3   -66.200969             4             0             0
3   -18.085927            11             5             0
```